# Toggle в новой версии jquery нету? Подскажите что нибудь подобное toggle.

Tags: jquery

Ставлю toggle на список li он весь исчезает! В интернете прочитал, что эту функцию убрали.

Comment: Какой именно **.toggle()**? Тот что привязывает [два и более обработчика](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)? Да, уже давно. А тот что [отображает/скрывает элементы](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/) - вроде как жив и здоров даже в версиях 2.x.

Comment: Хм, но в официальной доке она так не помечена http://api.jquery.com/toggle/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция `toggle` используемая для скрытия и показа элементов есть и в самой актуальной версии jQuery: [Effects > Basics > toggle](http://api.jquery.com/toggle/).

Если Вы о функции `toggle` связанной с событиями, позволяющей навешывать несколько обработчиков, в частности для каждого четного/нечетного клика, то она считается устаревшей начиная с jQuery 1.8, и была удалена в версии 1.9: [Deprecated > Deprecated 1.8 | Events > Mouse Events | Removed](http://api.jquery.com/toggle-event/)

---

Судя по всему Вы пытаетесь использовать функцию `toggle` связанную с событиями, но подключаете jQuery версии выше 1.8. Как вариант можно вешать обработчик на событие `click`,  и хранить в `data` элемента спец. флаг.

Comment: да, спасибо! Именно так и сделал

Comment: можно еще создать массив функций (можно его в data добавить)и делать его array.push(array.shift); http://jsfiddle.net/oceog/PETqD/